# search results in JSON format

Tags: search

I have a website built on drupal with search functionality. When I search for example for "test" the link of the search is displayed like `search/node/test`

Is there any possibility that if I call `search/node/test?json` or `search/node/test/json` the returned page would be plain text in json format of node ids ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Services Search](http://drupal.org/project/services_search) & [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module. Using these module you can expose search results as JSON.

Another option is [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module. Construct a page view which accepts search term as an argument and displays search results in JSON format.

Comment: the problem is i want the search results to display in same order as on the main site (clients u know) so by using another module rather than the search module , search results might change (too many filters applied)